# How to delete the content from text file while deleting from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, text-files

I am having a datagridview where the content of that datagridview will be from my sample text file. When i click on load i will have the data from sample.txt and that data in that text file is shown in the datagridview. I will have a checkbox column in my datagridview. If the user checks i will select the row and when user clicks delete button i would like to delete that text from the text file.

Suppose my text is as follows
[image]

If i click on the check box of first row and click on delete i would like to delete that text from text file

Comment: No offence, but is this for homework or are you just too lazy to code it yourself?

Comment: It is not a home work for me i am trying it myself

Comment: Did my answer help for your problem

Comment: In this case I'd recommend working through a beginner's book on .NET development. You are going to make progress much faster that way. SO is great if you have any specific questions, but you do need to have at least a minimal set of programming skills first if you want to make any progress...

Comment: I have not worked on WINFORMS so i came up with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textfiles - How to delete a line from a text file in C#? - Stack ...

[How to delete a line from a text file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668907/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-in-c)

See this link .

And some comments from me Here.

Read the all lines search the text u want and delete that text from list and write it in text file.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Text OBDC or OLE DB to access the text file contents?

You will have to:

- Decide from [FixedLength, Delimited/etc](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Providers/microsoft-text-odbc-driver), for the Text File Driver.
- Create a [Schema Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx).
- Use the [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile) to access the file.
- Use simple [oledb commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx) to process the data in file. Or use a data adapter.

  `string sql = "DELETE FROM yourFile WHERE ID=" + ID;`
  `ExecuteNonQuery(sql);`