# IndexOf does not correctly identify if a line starts with a value

Tags: c#

How can I remove a whole line from a text file if the first word matches to a variable I have?

What I'm currently trying is:

```
List<string> lineList = File.ReadAllLines(dir + "textFile.txt").ToList();
lineList = lineList.Where(x => x.IndexOf(user) <= 0).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(dir + "textFile.txt", lineList.ToArray());
```

But I can't get it to remove.

Comment: I flagged this for being a duplicate. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668907/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: Try to use startsWith method.

Comment: What is the error or problem you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mistake that you have is you are checking <= 0 with indexOf, instead of = 0.

-1 is returned when the string does not contain the searched for string.

<= 0  means either starts with or does not contain

=0 means starts with  <- This is what you want

Comment: +1, just keep in mind that `IndexOf(...) == 0` is not idiomatic for "starts with" and may confuse future developers.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: only the bad ones :p

Comment: @user1213488 just as a warning, you may encounter issues with the concept of first "word".  if user = abc, and the first "word" is actually abcdef, that line will still be returned.  You might need to do some more thorough parsing of the first "word"

Comment: @banging as I recall you were confused with = 0 vs < 0 in your own answer :P

Comment: @StefanH: I never claimed I was one of the good ones ;D But seriously I was confused with the requirements and not what =0 or <0 mean!

Answer (score 1):

This method will read the file line-by-line instead of all at once.  Also note that this implementation is case-sensitive.

It also assumes you aren't subjected to leading spaces.

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("temp.file"))
{
    //here I only write back what doesn't match
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("file").Where(x => !x.StartsWith(user)))
        writer.WriteLine(line);  // not sure if this will cause a double-space ?
}

File.Move("temp.file", "file");
```

Comment: Be careful with case sensitivity ;)

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close, [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) handles that nicely:

```
// nb: if you are case SENSITIVE remove the second argument to ll.StartsWith
File.WriteAllLines(
    path,
    File.ReadAllLines(path)
        .Where(ll => ll.StartsWith(user, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

For really large files that may not be well performing, instead:

```
// Write our new data to a temp file and read the old file On The Fly
var temp = Path.GetTempFileName();
try
{
    File.WriteAllLines(
        temp,
        File.ReadLines(path)
            .Where(
               ll => ll.StartsWith(user, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
    File.Copy(temp, path, true);
}
finally
{
    File.Delete(temp);
}
```

Another issue noted was that both `IndexOf` and `StartsWith` will treat `ABC` and `ABCDEF` as matches if the user is `ABC`:

```
var matcher = new Regex(
    @"^" + Regex.Escape(user) + @"\b", // <-- matches the first "word"
    RegexOptions.CaseInsensitive);
File.WriteAllLines(
    path,
    File.ReadAllLines(path)
        .Where(ll => matcher.IsMatch(ll)));
```

Comment: The OP only wants starts with, not contains

Comment: At least you pointed it out, so people don't think that I'm just a crazy person.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use  `= 0` instead of `<= 0`.
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate that IndexOf will return -1 when there is no match, therefore the OP is currently returning all lines that both start with user, and do not have user.

Comment: And I think you mean = 0 (Starts with) NOT <=0 (either starts with or does not contain) and NOT <0 (does not contain)