# Why is my Stream not Readable?

Tags: c#, file-io, uri, filestream, streamreader

This is a sequel to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429716/how-can-i-remove-the-oldest-lines-in-a-file-when-using-a-filestream-and-streamwr) about trimming the fat off a log file.

I have this code:

```
private readonly FileStream _fileStream;
private readonly StreamWriter _streamWriter;

. . .

    const int MAX_LINES_DESIRED = 1000;

    string uriPath = GetExecutionFolder() + "\\Application.log";
    string localPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
    if (!File.Exists(localPath))
    {
        File.Create(localPath);
    }
    _fileStream = File.OpenWrite(localPath);
    // First, remove the earliest lines from the file if it's grown too much
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileStream);
    . . .
```

Which fails on the last line shown with:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2147024809
  _message=Stream was not readable.
```

Why is it not readable? I thought maybe because the file was empty, but I added a line to it, and still get the same err msg.

Comment: Two things: 1) `File.Create` returns an open handle that might cause an exception if you try to open it again with `OpenWrite`. 2) `OpenWrite` does not return a readable stream. It opens for writing only, as the name is meant to imply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File.OpenWrite` creates a non-readable stream.  If you're going to be reading and writing to the stream, you need to use `File.Open(localPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)`.

Additionally, you can just use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, and that will remove the need for your `File.Exists` conditional.

Answer (score 1):

The error code in hex is `FFFFFFFF80070075` which equates to `E_INVALIDARG - One or more arguments are invalid`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx for the definitions of the error codes.

Based on this, the stream not readable message, and looking at the code, it looks like the open call should specify the ReadWrite file access attribute on the call.

Comment: If you mean OpenWrite() should be ReadWrite(), there seems to be no such animal.