# How can I prevent my file from being used by another process?

Tags: c#, file-io, process, filestream

This is a sequel to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431351/why-is-my-stream-not-readable?noredirect=1#27431447) where I was wondering why my stream was not fordable.

Utilizing ideas from some of the cats who answered the other question, I've now got this code:

```
private readonly FileStream _fileStream;
private readonly StreamWriter _streamWriter;

. . .

private ExceptionLoggingService()
{
    const int MAX_LINES_DESIRED = 1000;
    int linesInLogFile;

    string uriPath = GetExecutionFolder() + "\\Application.log";
    string logPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
    _fileStream = File.Open(logPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader _streamReader = new StreamReader(_fileStream);
    List<String> logList = new List<String>();

    while (!_streamReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        logList.Add(_streamReader.ReadLine());
    }
    linesInLogFile = logList.Count;
    while (logList.Count > MAX_LINES_DESIRED)
    {
        logList.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    if (linesInLogFile > MAX_LINES_DESIRED)
    {
        _fileStream.Close();
        File.Delete(logPath);
        File.Create(logPath);
        _fileStream.Close(); // added this; did not help
        _fileStream.Dispose(); // this also did no good
        _fileStream = File.OpenWrite(logPath); // <= exception occurs here
    }

    _streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_fileStream);

    foreach (String s in logList)
    {
        _streamWriter.WriteLine(s);
    }
    _streamWriter.Flush(); // here is okay, right (as opposed to within the foreach loop)?
}
```

...but on the indicated ("OpenWrite()") line I get the following exception (I added the two lines above it, first the call to Close(), then Dispose(), but the exception remains the same):

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2147024864
  _message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\HoldingTank\Sandbox\bin\Debug\Application.log' because it is being used by another process.
```

So if Close doesn't close _fileStream, and Dispose doesn't dispose it, what can be done?

### UPDATE

This doesn't strictly answer my question, but it works, inspired by Lloyd's comment:

```
const int MAX_FILESIZE_ALLOWED = 20000;
string uriPath = GetExecutionFolder() + "\\Application.log";
string logPath = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(logPath);
long fileLenInBytes = f.Length;
if (fileLenInBytes > MAX_FILESIZE_ALLOWED)
{
    File.Delete(logPath);
}
_fileStream = File.OpenWrite(logPath);
_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(_fileStream);
```

Comment: Idea is simple. Since you want to update your `Application.log` file (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429716/how-can-i-remove-the-oldest-lines-in-a-file-when-using-a-filestream-and-streamwr/) don't try to read and write it at the same time. Read your file, close it, write the result. It is not a magic.

Comment: Yes, the idea is simple; el Diablo is in the details.

Comment: Why you can't solve it after so many questions is because your inability, not because of comments or answers posted so far. For ex. I think my previous comment is the exact answer to your question. (Do you know how to implement it? then read the basic c# tutorials.)

Comment: Maybe so, but what I lack in brainpower I make up for in persistence.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Actually, according to the previous comment's sharpness - it seems you're fine in both :)

Comment: I feel like I am repeating myself. [`File.Create` returns an open handle to the file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431351/why-is-my-stream-not-readable?noredirect=1#comment43304037_27431351)

Comment: I am no longer using File.Create (see the Update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration, for example:

```
_fileStream = File.Open(logPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

You can use `FileShare.None` to lock the file, as described on MSDN:

> Declines sharing of the current file. Any request to open the file (by
>   this process or another process) will fail until the file is closed.

However, because this is logging I'd advise you to use something like `NLog` or `Log4Net` rather than rolling you own, let that deal with log output.

Comment: On the first File.Open() (not the File.OpenWrite()), right?

Comment: You'd want it on the first instance that you want to lock the file.

Comment: This is a Windows CE / Compact Framework app; I don't think those are available in this case (I do love Log4Net normally, though).

Comment: Well, the file conditionally gets destroyed, and then re-created, so I still don't know just what needs to happen here. Locking a file that then gets destroyed and resurrected doesn't seem to make sense. I tried every combination of that code (using it with my first assignment to _fileStream, my second, with both, and with the Close and Dispose calls intact and commented out - and in all cases I still get an IO exception.

Comment: I think reading in the file is wasteful. Why MAX_LINES_DESIRED rather than say a max log size? You can then just check the file size before acting. BTW NLog does support Windows Mobile iirc.