# Is it possible to edit a text file in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I need to delete one row in my text file. I use the `Windows.Storage.StorageFile` library to save my data.

Should I delete the file and create it again or there is a way to remove the line from the middle in UWP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite your file without the deleted line.

Look at "[How to delete a line from a text file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668907/how-to-delete-a-line-from-a-text-file-in-c)" - it's old (2009) and not tagged with UWP, but it covers the concept and applies to UWP as well, and C# in general.

For UWP you can use the code below:

```
var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
lines.RemoveAt(lineIndex);
await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, lines);
```